# Is there a blender UI addon that highlights the active menu the mouse cursor is hovering over?

Tags: interface, add-on, customization, color, theme

From what I understand so far about Blender, wherever the mouse cursor is hovering over, it becomes the active region.

Currently, Blender slightly changes the tint of a menu's header as you hover your cursor on and off from the menu. But that small change is barely noticeable.

Is there a blender UI addon that can let the user create a custom color for both the active and non-active **Headers** or active/non-active **Window Backgrounds**?

It helps to know what is active, especially on large high resolution monitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can just customize the theme in *User Preferences* and choose the colors to your requirement and then save the theme as well as make it the default.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open the *User Preferences* and then goto *Theme* tab.

[Customizing Blender Theme](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/themes.html)